# "App' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context." Getting this error while importing Realm in swiftui project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, realm

```
 import SwiftUI
 import RealmSwift

 @main
 struct RealmUpdatedDemoApp: App {
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ContentView()            
         }
     }
 }
```

On importing RealmSwift on the main App file, I am getting this error but not on other files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its a case of name collision, explicitly specify the namespace `SwiftUI` for `App`, if you want to import `RealmSwift` in this class:

Example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

@main
struct SwiftUITestApp: SwiftUI.App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RTXGamer it is working but can you explain or share any link to know about this in detail.

Comment: Search for 'namespace in swift'.